# Control TV Channels via HDMI via Raspberry Pi

Tags: hdmi

So I have:
1x LG 42" LED LCD TV
1x HDMI Cable
1x Raspberry Pi (Model B)

I have been looking around but did not find much on this topic except a disscussion on how to do this via SCART. I'm wondering if it would be possible to controll what Channel TV is playing via RPi.

Basically sending instructions to TV via RPi to increase/reduce volume, enter PIP mode or change channel. Would this be possible via RPi ?

I know the alternative is really more simple/trivial since TV has an auto switch to active HDMI port and I could simply have video feed go to tv via RPi have volume at max on tv and control volume output of RPi.

But really I'm wondering if the first is an option and if so where should I start looking ?

Comment: http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#CEC

Comment: RaspBMC / XBMC has CEC built in. More googling next time!

Answer (score 2):

You could use your raspberry pi as a IR remote and program it according to your model of TV.

http://www.stavros.io/posts/how-turn-your-raspberry-pi-infrared-remote-control/

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution, not the best, but you can give it a try.

http://www.cec-o-matic.com/ site has a lot of hdmi-cec commands.

You can install cec-client from package cec-utils.
With this tool you can send commands to tv.

Switching channels can be achieved by sending "Keypress" messages. Eg F0:44:20 sends the '0' key to the tv. Sending multiple messages, like 'F0:44:21' ; 'F0:44:20' should change the num 10 channel.

Volume changes mute, and a lot of other things can be achieved by this.

Example command line `echo 'tx 10 91' | cec-client`